# How to delete duplicate entries completely

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I have a column in excel, using vba I am trying to check if there is a duplicate entry in that column then delete duplicate and also main entry so there will be no value related to that entry anymore. What would be the way to do this ?

```
 Input column=>

  1
  2
  3
  1
  4
  5
  2

desired output column =>

 3
 4
 5
```

Actually my entries are text but, I gave numerical example to make it clear

After answers my code became

```
Last_Row = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

Columns("G:H").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G2", "G" & Last_Row) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("G1", "H" & Last_Row)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Dim i As Integer

i = 2
While (i < Last_Row + 1 And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 7).Value))
If Cells(i, 7) = Cells(i + 1, 7) Then
    Range("G" & i + 1, "H" & i + 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("G" & i, "H" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If

If Not Cells(i, 7) = Cells(i + 1, 7) Then
i = i + 1
End If

Wend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a macro Excel. Your Data should be in the first column and the worksheet to be called "Sheet1"

```
Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Columns("A")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Dim i As Integer
Dim b As Boolean

i = 1
b = False
While Cells(i, 1) > 0
    While Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1)
        Rows(i + 1).Delete
        b = True
    Wend
    If b = True Then
        Rows(i).Delete
        b = False
        i = i - 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Answer (score 2):

This works. I haven't tried to optimise it or anything.

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim vOut As Variant
Dim ditch() As Integer
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
'Read input column into 2D array
v = Range("A1:A7").Value
'Mark which inputs to ditch (mark as 1 if duplicate, keep at 0 if not)
ReDim ditch(LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1))
For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(v)
        If ditch(j) = 0 And v(j, 1) = v(i, 1) Then
            ditch(i) = 1
            ditch(j) = 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i
'How many non-duplicates are there?
n = UBound(v, 1) - LBound(v, 1) + 1 - WorksheetFunction.Sum(ditch)
'Put non-duplicates in new 2D array
ReDim vOut(1 To n, 1 To 1)
j = 0
For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    If ditch(i) = 0 Then
        j = j + 1
        vOut(j, 1) = v(i, 1)
    End If
Next i
'Write array to sheet
Range("B1").Resize(n).Value = vOut
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using VBA, a 'helper' column with `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)` copied down to suit,if your data starts in Row1, should identify duplicates. Filter on the helper column and delete rows showing values greater than `1` may be suitable for you.

Comment: thanks for the idea but I need to figure out a way to do in VBA or at least a way to record a macro using excel menu functions.

Comment: Since my main macro will do that that is why I am asking, I dont know honestly what I can paste here about my question. If there is a easy way, I appreciate, otherwise I will try to find any other way.

Comment: @user2937812 pnuts gave you exactly the steps you would need to record your own macro. You could then post another question if you needed help modifying what you already recorded.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007

> click the "Data" Tab in the ribbon 
>   Highlight your selection 
>   click "Remove Duplicates"

Comment: thanks but it only removes duplicates what I want to do is also removing original value if duplicate of that entry is available like in the example I gave.

Comment: I dont think there is an easy command in vba, you will have to build yur own, I will tell you my idea then try to code it. if you fail im sure some one here will help you. you can dim an array so it can store how many times does a word is reapeated. then if it is more than once you delete than row. you can save macros to know how to delete rows

Comment: Actually I was just wondering if there is a way like remove duplicate property of excel or any other simple way to solve. In the worst case I can deal with search method which requires at least 2-3 loops and many computations.